# XSLT remove all text nodes

Tags: xslt, textnode

I'm trying to remove text nodes without success from a XML document, this is the XSLT I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*">
        <xsl:element name="x">
            <xsl:attribute name="attr">
                <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*/a">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*/a/*">
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*/*[not(self::a)]" />
    <xsl:template match="text()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The line `<xsl:template match="text()">` probably it's not working because other lines are more specific (I think), how can I do to remove ALL text nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your template to suppress text nodes is suppressing all text nodes for which matching templates are sought.  But it's not suppressing all text nodes, because not all text nodes are processed using apply-templates.  When you encounter some nodes (those that match the match-patterns `/*/*/a/*` and `/*/*/*`, you are copying all of their child nodes without applying templates to them; if some of those children are text nodes, or others of those children have text-node descendants, those text nodes are escaping your scythe.  Get rid of the copy-of calls, then, and stick to copy with apply-templates.